# Adding Stroke And Fill To Score Label On Xcode

Tags: ios, label

I have been trying different sorts of codes to add a border around my label, but I only get a shadow from what I put in, but I am looking for a border unfortunately, and have tried to research it with no luck.  I kept getting errors putting in other codes.  Any help is appreciated.  Here is my code aswell for my shadow.

```
Score.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
Score.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(2.0f, 2.0f);
Score.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0f;
Score.layer.shadowRadius = 2.0f;
```

Thanks

Here is a gyazo of what I am looking for aswell

http://gyazo.com/e30c2371c8da364763f18027fc8bf141

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried a cgrect border?
you can change the matrices as such. Varitas

```
 layer = [CALayer layer];
 layer.position = CGPointMake ([self view].bounds.size.width /2, [self view].bounds.size.height          /3 );
layer.bounds= CGRectMake (100,100,1000,1000);
```

Comment: I tried to do that, but it is just showing use of undeclared item, am I supposed to be declaring anything for it?  Thanks :)

Comment: Thank you.  Where can I declare the item, I am new to coding, I am sorry for bothering you.  Also, how do I give you a point on this.